# Generated Google maps iframe not show without login

Tags: google-maps

I have problem with own generated Google maps. In "mapsengine.google.com" my client generate own map (url: https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zcP3_I5QxWSs.kxCl8Vd_qCPQ). After that he send me this iframe (

```
<iframe src="https://mapsengine.google.com/map/embed?mid=zcP3_I5QxWSs.kxCl8Vd_qCPQ" width="830" height="580"></iframe>
```

) and I add it to website (http://www.jaronet.cz/internet/#mapa-pokryti) then some users saw this map and another no. I check clients settings and I saw he select "public" to this map => this map can see everyone without login to Google account.

We tried change "src" from "https://..." to "http://..." but nothing solution. Then we tried next tip from internet = change "src" from "https://..." to "//..." but nothing solution.

Is there some solution?

Comment: Do you know exactly what the users are seeing instead of the map? Do they get an error message from Google, or a browser error, or a blank iframe, or ... ?

Comment: In IE user see iframe with some text - after click on him then he was redirect to login page in Google. In FF user see nothing only white place of same width/height as iframe. If user is login in Google account then see map in FF correctly.